# Реализация записной книги

Tags: ооп, delphi

Всем привет! Подскажите, как реализовать записную книжку в Delphi.
Я делаю записями:

```
type
  PAddress = ^TAddress;
  TAddress = record

  city:string;
  street  : string;
  end;

type
  PTPerson = ^TPerson;
  TPerson = record
    name    : string;
    secname :string;
    Addresses : TList;
  end;

 var
  person  : PTPerson;
  address : PAddress;
```

Получается, создаю указатели на person и address, заполняю. `Addresses` заполняю значениями из `PAddress`. 
Как можно реализовать такую структуру классом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте класс, объявите переменные `person` и `address` полями этого класса и реализуйте методы (например):

1. `addAddress`
2. `addPerson`
3. `delAddress` - с дополнительной, например private функцией, которая ищет (и что-то делает) удаляемый адрес в `person`
4. `delPerson`
5. `assignAddress` - добавляющая определенный адрес в `Addresses`

И так далее. В коде, будет что-то вроде (пример):

```
type
    TNoteBook = class
        private
            FPerson: PTPerson;
            FAddresses: PAddress;
        public
            constructor Create(); //выделение памяти, начальные значения и прочая лабуда
            procedure AddAddress(Address: TAddress);
            function GetPersonData(Name: String): TPerson;
            //... и т.д.
    end;
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. А как можно заменить использование записей?

Comment: @namesmile, использование каких записей вы хотите заменить?

Comment: @namesmile, можно вместо записей пользоваться объектами ("`type TPerson = class(TObject)`" etc.). Не уверен, что это оправдано, но можно.

Comment: @Dex, Record на объекты. Т.е. вместо полей записи использовать отдельный объект, а объекты объединить, скажем, в TList.

Comment: Можно и так, значения это не имеет. Любая абстрактная модель в данном контексте будет возможной.

Comment: @Sh4dow, почему Вы считаете, что это не оправданно? 
@Dex, а по-правильному? Придерживаясь концепции ООП, все же будет правильней создать отдельный объект, да? Но, как я понял, если на выходе мы получаем работающий вариант, то неважно к каким мы методам прибегали. Все, @Sh4dow, @Dex, спасибо за ответы, помогли разобраться.